# HTML anchor to send post data on click

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to make an anchor tag behave like a .submit (with certain post characteristics?) Reason why I have an anchor tag, because I dislike the submit button look and wanted a CSS button.

Here's what I'm doing right now (and it's not working)

html file

```
<div class="footer"><a href="#" id = "test_btn" class="button"><strong>Sign Up</strong></a></div>

<div class="footer"><a href="#" id = "test2_btn" class="button"><strong>Sign Up</strong></a></div>
```

the .js file

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#test_btn").live("click",function(){
    var post_data = {'account_type':"Free"}
    return $.post("www.someplacehere.com/user_sign_up/1/", post_data);
}); 

$("#test2_btn").live("click",function(){
    var post_data = {'account_type':"Premium"}
    return $.post("www.someplacehere.com/user_sign_up/1/", post_data);
}); 
</script>
```

I get a proper response, but it doesn't send me to the POST data page just redirects back to the top of the page (due to the anchor). Any ideas how to make it direct me to the right place (html page) with the POST data pre-filled on that html page? As you notice, it's not a simple `.submit()`.
Right now probably going to go with a hidden field and then do a `.submit()`, but wondering if there's an easier way to get the page since the POST could be done properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Everyone **stop** re-inventing buttons.  They already exist, and they can be styled too.

```
button[type=submit] {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: solid blue 1px;
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

demo'd here: http://jsfiddle.net/MZbLW/

---

I should also point out that everyone in the world is going to be looking for the traditional button at the end of the form, and making it look completely different may not be the greatest idea from a usability standpoint.

Comment: It's not about reinventing buttons, it's about using AJAX to submit data via a form.  Either way you'd have to cancel the default action.

Comment: @zzzz AJAX is irrelevant.  It's better to style a button to look like a link than it is to reimplement button functionality via a link.  If your custom styling breaks, the underlying functionality still works.

Comment: My vote for Bemace. There is no point in re-inventing the wheel. This is something which you can do just by plain html and css why do all the gymnastics??

Comment: Not everyone in the world will be looking for the traditional button at the end of the form, because it's not a traditional form, it's a choice between 2 buttons and that's all it is to a page. It's a nice UI that will determine which part of the next form will be pre-filled in. However, this did do the trick. So thanks =)!

Comment: @bemace I agree that it's better to style a button to keep the functionality; but if your advanced functionality (AJAX) requires javascript then you can perform a javascript replacement to get an element that is easier to style. I'm not saying it's the best way, I'm just saying that there are alternatives.

Comment: Great and all, but the CSS doesn't work for IE.  Due to IE suckage it still shows up as a button.

Comment: @Yada I laughed hard at ***IE suckage*** :D

Comment: This is not re-inventing the wheel, it is more trying out different variations of wheel. Also you can't nest forms inside forms, so anchors that are inside forms that do post might make sense in some situation

Answer (score 3):

In the click handler for the link, return false to stop the default action.

I also would just use the [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function, not live.

Answer (score 2):

Your click event needs to either return false, or prevent default.

Using AJAX is *Asynchronous* so you wont be returning the value, you'll have to find the value in the complete callback.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this probably comes closer:

```
$(a.submitLink).click(function () {
  $.post({data: values});

  $.post({data2: values2});

  return false;
});
```

The key here is that returning false prevents the default behavior for the link.  If you need to do additional processing based on the results of the post you'll do that inside a callback function.  There's no reason you can't issue several AJAX calls inside the function bound to your anchors, but you need to make sure the link doesn't function as a link as well.

Answer (score 0):

One quick thought why don't you try using

**<button type="submit" class="footer" >Signup</button>** 
instead of
**<input type=submit>**

This gives you flexibility of styling your button whatever way you want and have text in it as well. Besides you do not have to do all the hard work of creating custom button and posting it back.

Just give it a thought.